# Placement new in std::aligned_storage?

Tags: c++, c++14

Suppose I have a type template parameter T.

And suppose I have a `std::aligned_storage` as follows:

```
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type storage;
```

I want to placement new a T into the `storage`.

What is the standard-compliant pointer value/type to pass to the placement new operator, and how do I derive that from `storage`?

```
new (& ???) T(a,b,c);
```

For example:

```
new (&storage) T(a,b,c);
new (static_cast<void*>(&storage)) T(a,b,c);
new (reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage)) T(a,b,c);
new (static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(&storage));
```

Which of the above (if any) are compliant, and if none, what is the better way?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The most paranoid way is

```
::new ((void *)::std::addressof(storage)) T(a, b, c);
```

Explanation:

- `::std::addressof` guards against overloaded unary `operator&` on `storage`, which is technically allowed by the standard. (Though no sane implementation would do it.) The `::std` guards against any non-top-level namespaces (or classes) called `std` that might be in scope.
- `(void *)` (which in this case is the equivalent of a `static_cast`) ensures that you call the placement `operator new` taking a `void *` rather than something else like `decltype(storage) *`.
- `::new` skips any class-specific placement `operator new`s, ensuring that the call goes to the global one.

Together, this guarantees that the call goes to the library placement `operator new` taking a `void *`, and that the `T` is constructed at where `storage` is.

In most sane programs, though,

```
new (&storage) T(a,b,c);
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: OK, +1 for the sheer level of paranoia. If I ever embark on writing a Hell++ implementation, I'll ask you to collaborate :-)

Comment: @Nikos See https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/1896169 . "[C-style casts] are defined as the first of the following which succeeds: `const_cast`, `static_cast` (though ignoring access restrictions), `static_cast` (see above) then `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` then `const_cast`"

Answer (score 5):

The placement allocation function is described as follows (C++14 n4140 18.6.1.3):

> ```
> void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `ptr`.
>
> *Remarks:* Intentionally performs no other action.

20.10.7.6 table 57 describes `aligned_storage<Len, Align>` thus:

> The member typedef `type`
>   shall be a POD type suitable for use
>   as uninitialized storage for any object
>   whose size is at most *Len* and whose
>   alignment is a divisor of *Align.*

This implies that in your case, `&storage` is suitably aligned for holding an object of type `T`. Therefore, under normal circumstances<sup>1</sup>, all 4 ways you've listed of calling placement `new` are valid and equivalent. I would use the first one (`new (&storage)`) for brevity.

---

<sup>1</sup> T.C. correctly pointed out in the comments that it is technically possible for your program to declare an overload of the allocation function taking a `typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type*`, which would then be selected by overload resolution instead of the library-provided 'placement new' version.

I would say this unlikely in at least 99.999% of cases, but if you need to guard against that as well, use one of the casts to `void*`. The direct `static_cast<void*>(&storage)` is enough.

Also, if you're paranoid to this level, you should probably use `::new` instead of just `new` to bypass any class-specific allocation functions.

Comment: Only the version with a `void*` cast is guaranteed to go to the library placement new though.

Comment: Also, to be extra paranoid, `::new`.