# Constexpr initialization of an array of non-copyable objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, constexpr

I would like to have a class `B` which has 3 member objects of another class `A`. Constructors of both `A` and `B` are `constexpr`. `A` - which is contained inside `B` - is non-copyable and non-movable. This code builds correctly:

```
class A
{
public:
    constexpr explicit A(int a) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

class B
{
public:
    constexpr B() :
            a0{0},
            a1{1},
            a2{2}
    {}
private:
    A a0;
    A a1;
    A a2;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

However I would really like to have the 3 objects of type `A` as an array. If I try the simple approach like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    constexpr explicit A(int a) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

class B
{
public:
    constexpr B() :
            a{A{1}, A{2}, A{3}}
    {}
private:
    A a[3];
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

fails to build with:

```
$ g++ a.cpp 
a.cpp: In constructor ‘constexpr B::B()’:
a.cpp:21:22: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
    a{A{1}, A{2}, A{3}}
                      ^
a.cpp:13:2: note: declared here
  A(A&&) = delete;
  ^
a.cpp:21:22: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
    a{A{1}, A{2}, A{3}}
                      ^
a.cpp:13:2: note: declared here
  A(A&&) = delete;
  ^
a.cpp:21:22: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
    a{A{1}, A{2}, A{3}}
                      ^
a.cpp:13:2: note: declared here
  A(A&&) = delete;
  ^
a.cpp:28:2: error: member ‘B::a’ must be initialized by mem-initializer in ‘constexpr’ constructor
  }
  ^
a.cpp:32:7: note: declared here
  A a[3];
       ^
```

Is it possible to solve **without** making `A` movable?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @rustyx I've changed the code a bit and it works fine for C++11 and C++17 (with `explicit`). However - as usually - the real code is a bit more complex. Let's say that `A` is **really** non-movable and non-copyable, say that it has a destructor.

```
class A
{
public:
    constexpr explicit A(int a) {}
    ~A() {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

class B
{
public:
    constexpr B() :
            a{A{1}, A{2}, A{3}}
    {}
private:
    A a[3];
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

This fails even with C++17:

```
g++ a.cpp -std=c++17
a.cpp: In constructor ‘constexpr B::B()’:
a.cpp:14:22: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
    a{A{1}, A{2}, A{3}}
                      ^
a.cpp:7:2: note: declared here
  A(A&&) = delete;
  ^
a.cpp:14:22: error: non-constant array initialization
    a{A{1}, A{2}, A{3}}
                      ^
a.cpp:15:3: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
  {}
   ^
a.cpp:7:2: note: declared here
  A(A&&) = delete;
  ^
```

It fails also if `A`'s constructor is not `explicit`. If I remove the destructor then it works, but what if the destructor has to be there? Is there a solution to this particular array-initialization problem or am I out of luck here?

Comment: Hav you tried adding the C++17 flag to your compile command: `g++ -std=c++17 a.cpp`?! Works for me with g++ and clang.

Comment: @lubgr - is there a c++11 solution for this problem?

Comment: If you can remove the `explicit` in the `A` constructor, should works with `a{ {1}, {2}, {3} }` (also C++11/C++14).

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, initializing an instance of `A` from `A{1}` is a *copy-* (or move) initialization. Most compilers elide the copy/move and don't even bother calling the copy/move constructor, but only starting from C++17 is presence of a copy/move constructor actually not required.

As a workaround you can remove `explicit` from `A`s constructor and construct `A`s in-place:

```
class A
{
public:
    constexpr A(int a) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

class B
{
public:
    constexpr B() :
            a{{1}, {2}, {3}}
    {}
private:
    A a[3];
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

**=== EDIT ===** (in response to question edit)

> *Let's say that A is really non-movable and non-copyable, say that it has a destructor.*

The only possible workaround I can think of is the [nuclear option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187732/placement-new-in-stdaligned-storage) a.k.a. placement-new:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
class A
{
public:
    constexpr A(int a) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    ~A() {}
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {
        new (std::addressof(a[0])) A(1);
        new (std::addressof(a[1])) A(2);
        new (std::addressof(a[2])) A(3);
    }
    A& getA(size_t offset) { return reinterpret_cast<A*>(a)[offset]; }
private:
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A), alignof(A)>::type a[3];
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this works in the simple case, but as usually the real code is a bit more complex (; Could you please take a look at my edited question?